# Android: Allow TextView to be Dragged Outside of RelativeLayout

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, textview, imageview, drag

I've created an OnTouchListener that will allow me to drag views around the screen. This works well, except for one problem:

My views resize instead of leaving the parent. They are in a RelativeLayout, which I suspect is contributing to the problem. They only resize when touching the right or bottom boundaries of my RelativeLayout.

I'm hoping there is a simple solution to this problem, (ideally not involving resizing the RelativeLayout), but I haven't found a solution yet.

Ideally, this solution would be applicable for all views, as I use this OnTouchListener for TextViews as well as ImageViews. I was hoping to find an XML solution. I'm assuming others have dealt with this issue??

PS: Before I post this..I've just remembered I believe there is a flag for hitting a RelativeLayout's border, so maybe I can apply negative margin to the TextView when that happens. Thoughts?

### EDIT

Here is my OnTouchListener:

```
// Dragging functionality for all views and double tap to remove
// functionality for ImageViews
final OnTouchListener onTouchListener = new OnTouchListener()
{
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
    {
        v.bringToFront(); 

        //if(v instanceof android.widget.ImageView) 
            //mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event);

        layoutParams = (LayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();

        switch (event.getActionMasked())
        {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            // Where the user started the drag
            pressed_x = (int) event.getRawX();
            pressed_y = (int) event.getRawY();

            if (v instanceof android.widget.ImageView)
            {
                curTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                if(curTime - prevTime <= DOUBLE_TAP_INTERVAL)
                {
                    v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                prevTime = curTime;
            }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            // Where the user's finger is during the drag
            final int x = (int) event.getRawX();
            final int y = (int) event.getRawY();

            // Calculate change in x and change in y
            dx = x - pressed_x;
            dy = y - pressed_y;

            // Update the margins
            layoutParams.leftMargin += dx;
            layoutParams.topMargin += dy;
            v.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

            // Save where the user's finger was for the next ACTION_MOVE
            pressed_x = x;
            pressed_y = y;
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: where is your code for the problem? I tried doing this, and didnt need to set any negative margin for anything, you just reset the left and top corners of the given view, and it slides off the screen on its own

Comment: Probably you can post  `activity.xml` and `yourActvity.java` code. It becomes easier then to understand the problem .

Comment: I added my OnTouchListener. It has some other functionality as well.